# Finding a character from a column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a pipe(|) separated string, I need to find the first character in the 7th column of that pipe-separated string

```
AAAAAA|04|XXXXXXX|20170210-163119|||2.0|20170208||
```

Expected output : 2

Comment: expected output is 2 or 2.0?

Comment: use [substr](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-substr_0028_0029-function) on `$7`

Comment: `sed -ne 's/|/\n/6; s/.*\n\(.\)/\1\n/; P'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
awk -F "|" '{print(substr($7,1,1))}' input.file.txt
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use cut:

```
cut -d\| -f7 | cut -c1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash

```
IFS='|' read -r -a x <<< "$str"
echo "${x[7]:0:1}"
```

`read` command uses the contents of $str and splits them on the `pipe |` char and fills them into an array (`-a`) named x. Then we extract one character from the beginning of the 7th field.

## Perl

```
perl -F'\|' -pale '($_) = $F[6] =~ /./g' <<< "$str"
```

`-F` => field separator, `-p` => autoprint mode, `-a` => autosplit turned on, `-l` => set up the record separator(`RS`) to `\n` and `ORS` to `\n`.

7th field `$F[6]` is evaluated in a list context and as `/./g` and returns individual chars, of which the first is picked and stored in the `$_` which due to the `autoprint` will take it to `stdout`.

## Expr

```
sep='|'
fld="[^$sep]*"
fld7=$(yes "$fld$sep" | sed 7q | tr -d '\n')
expr "$str" : "$fld7\(.\)"
```

Here we construct the command so that `expr` does it's job `under the hood`.

`echo "$fld";  # => [^|]*`
`echo "$fld7"; # => [^|]*[^|]*` .... 7 times

Answer (score 1):

Using `python3`, *assuming column 7 exists on all lines in the file*:

```
python3 -c "[print(l.split('|')[6][0]) for l in open('f').readlines()]"

> 2
```

Where `'f'` is the (full) path to the file, in single quotes.

#### Explanation

```
open('f').readlines()
```

will read the file *per line*, and

```
s.split('|')[6][0]
```

will split the line by the delimeter `|`, and subsequently print the first character of the 7th column (where 0 is the index of the first column)

Answer (score 1):

To study the interesting **sed** behavior

```
sed 's/\(\([^|]\?\)[^|]*|\)\{7\}.*/\2/' input.file.txt
```

or to reduce escaping

```
sed -r 's/(([^|]?)[^|]*\|){7}.*/\2/' input.file.txt
```

or to avoid regex

```
sed '/\n/{s/./\n/2;P;d;};s/|/\n/6;s/$/\n/;D' input.file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
awk -F'[|.]' '{print $7}' filename.txt
```

Comment: This only works for cases where i) there is only 1 `.` on the line and ii) that `.` is the 2nd character of the 7th field.